# Button in cell is being added when it is not supposed to be

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

So I have a settings button and it is only supposed to be added to the cell with the current users name. However, it seems to being randomly added to a cell. In the statement in which I create the button it is only being *created once* however it is being added to multiple cells. I have attached images of the problem and ps the current username is "test", so the settings button should not be in the same cell as the matt short user. Thanks and below is the attached code of the function in which i am creating and adding the button subview.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell : UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("chatCell") as? UITableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "chatCell")
    }

    cell!.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height

    var sectionTitle = self.friendSectionTitles[indexPath.section]
    var friendArray: [String]! = friendDict[sectionTitle]
    var friend = friendArray[indexPath.row]

    if sectionTitle == "me" && friend == PFUser.currentUser().username {
        var settingsButton: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        settingsButton.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth - 100 , 5, 50, 30)
        settingsButton.addTarget(self, action: "settingsButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        settingsButton.setTitle("Settings", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cell!.addSubview(settingsButton)
    }

    cell!.textLabel!.text = friend

    return cell!
}
```

[image: image of the table view with settings button in the appropriate area][image: image of the table view where the settings button was put in the inappropriate cell]

Comment: You need to understand cell reuse. When the cell that has the button added is reused (in some other row), the button will still be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the statement in which I create the button it is only being created once however it is being added to multiple cells

Because cells, once created, are reused for other rows of the table. If you don't want the button to appear in a reused cell, you will need (in your implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`) to detect its presence *and remove it* (or at least hide it) for every row that is *not* supposed to have it.

Comment: It might help you to read my explanation here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_the_three_big_questions

Comment: Just implemented this and it solved the problem thanks.